# Concatenating a Input Variable into another with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to figure out if possible to using `os.listdir` on a remote PC.

I want to have user input for a computer name and then take that and use `os.listdir` to list a certain directory on that PC.

```
import os

def listdirtory():
    computername = input("What is the computer name? ")
    completepath = "\\" + computername + "\C$\\users"
    os.listdir(completepath)

listdirtory()
```

Where I am having trouble is I need to take out the second `\` after 
   computername and one `\` after users since its reading the path with double \ 
   like this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\\testmachine\\\C$\\\users'
```

where it would need to be `\\\testmachine\C$\users\`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either escape a literal backslash with another backslash:

```
completepath = "\\\\" + computername + "\\C$\\users"
```

or use raw strings instead:

```
completepath = r"\\" + computername + r"\C$\users"
```

Comment: If you want it to work on all OS, you should use `os.path.join()` instead of concatenating with `+`.